# In SSRS, does the 'swich' statement execute all options, then only return the one with the true condition?

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement

I am using the switch statement in SSRS as shown.

```
=switch(Fields!TOTAL_TIME_HRS.Value=0, 0,
Fields!TOTAL_TIME_HRS.Value<0, -1,
Fields!TOTAL_TIME_HRS.Value>0, 1/Fields!TOTAL_TIME_HRS.Value)
```

Executing my report throws a divide by zero warning and for rows that the Fields!TOTAL_TIME_HRS.Value does equal 0, the result on the report is "#Error".  Shouldn't the switch statement be catching the possible error, and avoiding it?

Answer (score 0):

No. SSRS evaluate both sides regardless

One way to get around this is to put some VB code in your report to handle the possible divide by zero error

right click on your report and select report properties - go to the code tab and enter the following code

```
Public Function NDZ(Byval a As Decimal,Byval b As Decimal, Byval c As Decimal) As Decimal
'  Fix for divide by zero problem in VB
' calculates  a/b  and either returns result or c if b = 0 


if b = 0 then 
    return c 
else 
    return a/b 
end if 

end function
```

now in your report on the cell you want to do the division..

enter the following :

```
=code.NDZ(1,Fields!TOTAL_TIME_HRS.Value,0)
```

or you can simply replace the division part in your switch statement with the = code.ndz bit